# Materialism can cover idealism but idealism cannot cover materialism?

Tags: idealism, materialism

It seems to me that materialism can cover idealism, but not the contrary.

A materialist can recognize that reality is in part made of ideas, simply by saying that ideas are made of a bunch of materialistic entities, and circulate via a bunch of materialistic entities.

But this is not the case of idealism. Idealism can not recognize materialism.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Perhaps give some background of what motivates the question. What are you looking for?

Comment: It's the other way around. Materialism cannot account for non-material ideas, but idealism can easily account for the material world.

Comment: Presumably, either can cover the other, but not in the same [category of being](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_being). To avoid unnecessary confusion, note that each has both a *noumenal aspect* and a *phenomenal aspect*. One option is *materialism (noumenon)* contains *brain* contains *consciousness* contains *idealism (phenomenon)*. Another option is *idealism (noumenon)* roughly equals or contains *consciousness* contains *materialism (phenomenon)*.

Comment: The generalized concept of "physical" or "material" beings *can* be seen as idealized already, unless the concept of the physical is set *opposite* of the ideal. For example, Aristotle's definition of substance involves treating the physical world as composed of subject-predicate relations regardless of contingent language, with pure subjects = substance, a seemingly idealistic definition, but applied comprehensively to empirical nature. But when pure idealism can't cover matter, it's because of matter defined opposite non-matter, which leaves pure materialism not covering idealism either.

Comment: from wikipedia: > Idealism [...] is the set of metaphysical perspectives asserting that, most fundamentally, reality is equivalent to mind, spirit, or consciousness; that reality is entirely a mental construct; or that ideas are the highest form of reality or have the greatest claim to being considered "real". There are many flavors of idealism, but the main core idea seems to be that, in the end, anything you can touch hear or feel is but a representation occuring in your mind. All the information about the world we have access to is made of intuition and memories, all of which are ideas (whi

Comment: @DavidGudeman this would be a problem if only there was a way to demonstrate the existence of those non-material ideas nobody has ever seen... materialism of course rejects the very ides that there are non-material things. Please try and be consistent.

Comment: @armand, there was nothing inconsistent about what I said. Please try not to be so snotty.

Comment: @DavidGudeman i'm sure even you can see what is inconsistent in "materialism can't account for that thing it says does not exist and therefore does not have to account for"...

Comment: @armand, no, it is not inconsistent. It is not even odd. It would be a perfectly fine philosophical point even if your assumption were true and "materialism" did imply that the thing does not exist because if it did, my point would still be true. But materialism implies no such thing. In fact, most materialists believe that minds and mental phenomena do exist; they just think they are reducible to material things. But they have no idea how such a reduction might work, and so they cannot account for it.

Comment: @DavidGudeman you are moving the goalpost by conflating mental states and immaterial ideas. I hope it's not on purpose. People who think immaterial ideas exist are not materialist. Hence, your first point is wrong.

Comment: @armand, no, I'm not conflating the two. Your snotty comment about hoping it's not deliberate is inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Using your terms, idealism can "cover" materialism.

Picture a video game. Inside the game, physical objects are simulated by calculating what their interactions should be according to a set of mathematical rules. The physics of the simulated world are created by the consistent application of the rules.

The computer, of course, is itself physical, and it creates the simulation physically. But a sufficiently strong intellect could create a "physical" universe mentally just by imagining the objects in it, and making them interact according to consistent laws.

You can even do this yourself, at a much more modest scale. Just imagine a ball bouncing on the ground, and gradually coming to rest.  You just created a very small physical universe, mentally.

Answer (score 0):

Corroborating Dcleve's rightly-headed answer I want to make a fine  but significant correction that **physicalism** can't even *in principle* account for mind and consciousness for reasons already explored or alluded to in literature on "the hard problem of consciousness", that I briefly summarize here.

**Eliminativism** somehow pretends something that is there is not there by assuming that consciousness is identical with some brain state or an illusion. But...

**Identity theories** provide no argument but only assert correlations to be identities, that is, phenomenally distinct data (of neuroscience and of conscious experience) are not actually distinct but the same, which is of course question begging, in addition to contradicting the logical principle of [identity of indiscernibles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles) and its opposite non-identity of discernibles.

**Illusionist** accounts, [as I have explained and sustained it elsewhere](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/103103/the-ultimate-absurdity-if-consciousness-is-an-illusion-how-can-anything-we-kno), lead to logical contradiction, which is due to their mistaking consciousness (for which correspondence is meaningless, and which is rather *the ground* of all correspondence) with its particular states that can be true or false via correspondence.

**Representationalism** assumes representations are somehow possible without consciousness which is clearly not, for you can have no representation without being first conscious because all representations occur *inside* your consciousness. And forget about computer analogies as they are only false analogies. No bunch of electrical charges or frequencies inside a computer converted into pixel symbols on screen represent anything without us *consciously reading **meanings** into those symbols by awareness of our human lingual and/or engineering conventions.*

**Emergentism** can't explain how matter can give rise to something which is ontologically categorically different from matter, or the peculiar feature of the alleged emergent property to subsume everything even its own origin, matter, inside its mysterious *subsumptive* power.

**Epiphenomenalism** while not strictly a physicalist position posits consciousness as an idle by-product of the brain machinery but can't explain why should there be such a by-product in the first place, let alone able to produce such peculiar features as unity, subsumptive power, meaning, intentionality, etc.

**Idealism**, therefore, emerges as the only alternative, after all forms of the diehard physicalism defeated. Now Idealism *can* actually explain matter, whatever its exact scientific definition, by postulating that *all matter are only various determinations of consciousness.* The only problem however is that it implies some sort of a subjectivist non-realist demonology, as if our minds (*us ourselves* actually!) are some self-deceiving supernatural entities that can create and project the phenomenal world before our eyes without it (us!) normally making notice of our entire self-made show!

But a particular form of **panpsychism** can help us avoid this "crazy" (maybe even logically absurd) scenario, by *postulating a universal/cosmic consciousness inside which all determinations understood as "matter" take place giving us the very real physical world, with human mind being some sort of a highly restricted and degraded offshoot of that supreme consciousness that perceives those determinations by partially participating in that higher consciousness.*

I have find this hypothesis the only remaining view that is logically consistent, which is really *so much* because the foremost issue in mind-body relation debates are still the issue of logical consistency. Note that on this account, no datum of experience is ignored or dismissed or reduced, including the reality of the physical world!

With so much resolved, what I still found to be *specially* reassuring was that this only plausible view has been also empirically corroborated by that single revolutionary work that I have cited in my earlier answers two times already [*Irreducible Mind*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_Mind) by Edward F. Kelly et al. The authors have complied several category of empirical evidence from parapsychology that support the above picture, one that had been already proposed by F. W. H. Myers, a colleague of William James, more than a century ago but simply ignored and forgotten due to the rise of crude behaviorism and its blinding lure!

Comment: so what is the world and body in idealism? mind, but how does a mind construct (or even give the impression of, without a substrate?) matter? sorry for my ignorance, but i can't get my head around the idea of minds having a mental substrate

Comment: @prof_post, Body and the world are determinations of some really powerful mind on this account. This supposes that consciousness is most fundamental and inherently creative. Just imagine how you can just conjure up a phoenix in your mind. That's pretty much how the world and body came to be out there by a superior consciousness. Yes, that looks like some sort of theology but that's the only consistent scenario.

Comment: so it can cover it, but not with as much explanatory ease. though i suppose vice versa is tricky too

Comment: @prof_post Key point is that the above proposal is logically consistent, whereas physicalism is not. Furthermore, Irreducible Mind cites evidence for higher states of consciousness ("mystical") inspiring creative works of art, which really corroborates the point about a universal consciousness having created the natural world as products of its inherent creativity.

Comment: ok thanks for reply

Comment: All of the options you list are actually logically possible.  The "Hard Problem of Consciousness" is not that the solutions proposed by physicalists could not have possibly been true, but that they all are falsified by test.

Comment: @Dcleve I don't see which tests you are talking about. Philosophy doesn't work by tests but by analysis and inference. The hard problem argument maintains that there's a stark phenomenal distinction between data of subjective experience and physical data, therefore the two can't be equated or reduced to one another. But may use a softer language like "they seem difficult to reconcile" but deep analysis shows it is really a problem of logical impossibility as I have shown in my answer.

Comment: Well, SOME APPARENT things can be eliminated by thoroughgoing reduction.  Eliminative materialism is not false in principle, it only fails in THIS application, because there is value at the non-reduced level, above and beyond the reduction.  Identity Theories are not false in principle, they only fail because they all fail the "identity of indiscernibles" test.  And sometimes we ARE deluded about what we thought was evidence.  We generally need strong justification to dismiss evidence as delusion, which is a high bar the delusionists do not meet.  Etc.

Comment: @Dcleve As for Illusionist Eliminvativism I have argued and shown in the linked answer how it is logically absurd. And since Identity of indiscernibles is a logical principle, it makes Identity theory illogical or false in principle. In general, theories that are verified or falsified by mere analysis (instead of empirical data) are true or false in principle, i.e. by logical validity or consistency.

Comment: Illusionism is not absurd.  We know we have illusions.  We know we are mistaken about many aspects of our mental processing, and our data from introspection is seriously flawed.  We know we are sometimes mistaken about what we consider to be base data.  Asserting this to be true about consciousness is not absurd, it is instead a radical over extrapolation from a limited data set of partial delusions.  Your belief we could not reach conclusions if we were not conscious is itself falsified by test, and our unconscious System 1 that does 99% plus of our thinking, with no qualia whatsoever.

Comment: That consciousness is not indiscernible from either neural operation, or functional processing, depending on the type of identity theory, is an empirical observation about consciousness.  It could have been the case that we always don't have consciousness when we don't have the specific function or neurology that is an identity, and vice versa.  But that ISN'T the case for us humans, and how consciousness works.  Identity theory is falsified by test, because we can find cases of the "identity" when we don't have consciousness, or consciousness when we don't have the postulated identity.

Comment: @Dcleve We are certainly conscious during System 1 thinking. We only happen not to remember it afterwards and exert effort for deliberation. Evidence of that is that we remember chapters of it when something special catches our attention, focusing our consciousness. Therefore, any thought process without consciousness is absurd. Consciousness is ground of all cognition. Illusionism confuses properties of mental states with consciousness as I have explained in the linked answer. It is also self-contradictory.

Comment: @Dcleve I think the you are mistaken about the meaning of the indiscernibility principle in the context of consciousness. That consciousness is discernible from neural data is self-evident in the sense that we get to kinds of datum from subjective experience of consciousness (thoughts, sensations, emotions etc) as opposed when studying the neural correlates (neurons firing etc). Thoughts vs neurons are two category of phenomena, i.e. discernible. To say that they are identical is to deny the obvious.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151722/discussion-between-dcleve-and-infatuated).

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Physics is *experience*, arranged in economical order
> 2. Science always has its origin in the adaptation of *thought* to some definite field of *experience*
> 3. Bodies do not produce sensations, but complexes of elements ie. *complexes of sensations* make up bodies
> 4. Atoms are not real, only sensations are real
>    <sup>Note in the nineteenth century the modern atomic theory was cutting edge and [speculative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Mach)</sup>

That's Ernst Mach, one of the foremost physicists of the 19th century and an inspiration to Einstein.

So yes idealism cannot 'cover' material-**ism**
But it 'covers' matter well enough

#### Notes

1. Your verb 'cover' is not a usage I'm familiar with. I've used it as 'explain'
2. Not too many people would call Mach an idealist. He's better known for a phenomenological stand for physics. But for the purposes of this question that comes to the same
3. Explanation is not the same as effectiveness or prediction capability. We can assume that even staunch idealists consult doctors trained in the conventional — ie. materialistic — tradition!

Comment: The studies of how our minds work have revealed that we do lots of thinking unconsciously.  System 1 is unconscious, and does its thinking prior to creating "experience".  System 1 communicates a digest of our sensing to system 2, and that communication is through qualia.  Mach's claim that experience is a prerequisite for thought, is not true of our own unconscious minds.  The best of the "delusionist" books is "Incognito".  It is worth a read.

Comment: @Dcleve Well Mach was living in the 19th century. You need to allow that as slack!

Answer (score -1):

Materialism was refuted by physics, specifically Einstein, when matter was shown just to be a state of energy.

The effort to salvage materialism by assuming "physicalism" is itself refuted by the nature of physics as a field of study, rather than an ontology.   The explicit statement of one aspect of this problem is called Hempel's dilemma.  Another is that neither physics nor science are stand-alone fields -- they are incapable of establishing a standard of epistemic knowledge, and are entirely dependent on philosophy to do so.

Pragmatically, most physicalists assume that both information and logic exist, and neither are material.  One cannot DO physics with only matter, or energy.  One needs both information about the matter/energy, AND a valid reasoning methodology.  Both of these fall into the category of "abstract objects", or Popper's World 3, so this is effectively a dualist worldview, although it is a matter/abstraction dualism, not a matter/consciousness dualism.

Generating abstractions or consciousness from matter or energy (or from functions/algorithms, as per above, physics assumes their existence too) -- has proven to be a hard nut.  A variety of solutions have been proposed for the "hard problem of consciousness" or the "hard problem of abstractions" from a physicalist POV, but so far, they fail test cases, and/or thought problems.  In principle, both are at least possibly solveable, but pragmatically that has not been achieved.

Idealism is less clear than physicalism, as some idealisms are of abstractions, others are of awareness, and the two are very different. Idealisms face the same problem of physicalism, they require the spawning or explanation of very different states from a base state. Matter, and physics, would need to be generated in some way either by abstractions, or by minds, and as matter and physics are very different from either abstract concepts or the experiencing of minds, there is an analogous "hard problem of matter" for idealism. This generation is possible in principle, just as is the materialist hypothesis of minds and abstractions being generated by matter, but likewise faces challenges as to whether any proposal made by idealists is actually valid pragmatically or not.  In particular, the commonality of matter between different minds is very difficult to explain.

The most productive route for any monist ontologic theory is to invoke strong emergence, where emergence laws or relationships from the substrate create the emergent structure of some other radically different thing than the substrate.  This brings its own problems, as emergence is a very poorly understood concept and theory, and there ARE no general rules and principals as to when emergence happens, nor what new thing might emerge.

The other alternative is to just treat minds, physics, and abstractions as their own separate ontologies.  This is what spiritual dualism does for minds, and abstract realism does for abstractions.  Treating all three as separate ontologically is called Triplism, and Frege, Popper, and Penrose are the most notable advocates of ontological triplism.  Both dualism and triplism require interaction principles between these ontologically distinct substrates, which is its own complexity, similar in magnitude but (to my mind) less complex than developing a set of emergence laws.

Comment: I think of energy as physical. It certainly isn't an idea.

Comment: Pre-GR, energy was seen as a property of matter, and as such part of materialism.  Physics was just a science that studied matter.  Post GR, matter is a property of energy, but what energy IS -- is vague.  And physics is a field of science, without any specific ontology.  But yes, energy would be part of what physics studies.

Comment: Mass isn't a state of energy and matter isn't mass. Mass is (representable as) a bivariable function of energy and momentum, m^2=E^2/c^4-p^2/c^2. Matter is (representable as) particles with mass. However, particles with (and without) mass have [characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_number) that are not reducible to mass-energy-momentum, e.g. electric charge.

Comment: @gs -- WHAT mass or matter is -- is no longer clear in physics.  Essentialism, defining what the base elements of the universe are, is no longer really being practices in physics.  As you illustrated in your effort to characterize mass, physics has resorted instead just to math equations -- and this is exemplified by the exhortation response to "what does it mean?": "shut up and calculate".  The primary essentialist inclinations among physicists today tend toward MATH reductionism, that physics (and therefore matter) is "essentially" just math.  Which is -- interestingly, actually IDEALISM!!!

Comment: "The most productive route for any monist ontologic theory is to invoke strong emergence. This brings its own problems, as emergence is a very poorly understood concept and theory."  The main confusion here is the distinction between weak and strong emergence. The latter is just a lot of the former. The key distinction is between cummulative and non-cummulative emergence. Any wave washing on the shore is a form of emergence, but it doesn't build anything, on which the next wave could add. Biological evolution, on the other hand, is cumulative.

Comment: @Olivier5 Weak emergence is the thesis that we use emergence as a temporary stand in, until we gain the knowledge to figure out how to replace it with reduction. Strong emergence is the thesis that it is not an issue of sufficient knowledge, that a bottoms up approach can never work for some phenomenon.  SE is not just more of WE.  The case for SE was made by: a) phase changes, b) multiple realizability, c) dramatic stalling of scientific reduction in most sciences, d) the logic failings of SR vs philosophy, and the arts/humanities.  Strong emergence plus pluralism is dominant Phil of Science.

Comment: If that's how they define "weak emergence", then it is not emerging at all - so it's just a poorly conceived idea. The idea of emergence first came to me from biology (François Jacob). It was crystal clear.

Comment: Request you to expand on *Physicalism is necessarily dualist*. +1 anyway. Your comment  above — *physics =math imples idealism* belong in answer [I just happened to notice them]

Comment: @rishi -- Expanded a bit.

Comment: Tnx. Small quibble *... matter and physics...* this is a category mistake *especially if one is not a physicalist* but has some sense of the dualist/idealist perspective. See end of my [answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/109905/37256)