# How to see a subject within an object?

Tags: consciousness, metaphilosophy, subjectivity, panpsychism, gnoseology

One can explore a thing (and its sense) only forcing it to suffer (i.e. to interact with a human's consciousness) and bounding it in ideal and material worlds: its will, freedom, ability to gnosis and perception, making the gnosis dependent on a human's consciousness.

The actual component of a thing and its essence (metaidea, idea over idea) as a pra-thinking exist independently of our opinions and actions. Just as the ancients discovered the miraculous properties of wood, stone or flame for them.  We, discovering a new one, experiment on it, dissect a thing with thought, word, or deed, transfer its pragmatic part to the world of ordinary human thinking. Leaving concepts alone. We create the good in such a way that, in my understanding, there is a desire for harmony and indifference (to the perfection of nature: man sows the uncertainty of being through his prism of perception) in relation to everything subject-conceivable.

Absolute good is unattainable, because a person exists by his reality (actions and praxis), idea (consciousness and thinking) and matter (intention for actions), affecting all worlds simultaneously and instantly. God is the embodiment of absolute goodness. God is that which is indifferent to everything. As an axiom, I take continuity in time and the very continuity of the connection of thinking, cognition and consciousness. I say that they replace each other without gaps, allowing metamorphoses to be realized; otherwise, the law of the existence of the personal universe as such would be violated.

So, how can one see the subject within an object? How can one understand that a thing is able to think, perceive and so on?

Does it make sense to talk of perception other than through our own consciousness?

Is consciousness universal?

Whose thoughts are alike to mine? What books should I read to understand the subjective properties of an object?

Comment: interesting, though dense, thanks.

Comment: @prof_ghost could you be that kindest to recommend me some authors that considered the matter of my questions in the same way as I do?

Comment: not really, for which i apologize, yes. i can relate to the ideals rather than the phrasing :)

Comment: @prof_ghost why did my text seem dense to you?

Comment: lots of ideas, few paragraphs.

Comment: Indeed Cartesian dualistic worldview of the subject and object makes this impossible since you already assumed the mutual exclusive relation between them, but contemporary cognitive science supports the embodied consciousness thesis, thus to understand that a thing is able to think, perceive and so on is nothing else but to embed and merge such understanding into the environment as some monistic whole to treat the world as its own model...

Comment: @DoubleKnot thanks a lot! But I do not understand what you mean by saying 'to try to embed and merge such understanding into the environment as some monistic whole'. As for me, there is such thing as pra-consciousness, which makes the world of ideas and the world of materia exist. Also, I think, the environment exists independent of our seeing, feeling, consciousness and so on.

Comment: There may be darkness to prevent you from seeing possible dependence, and pra means prajña which could be said to be consistent with such embedding as some form of reflection to pull back both the objective and the subjective like an arc in order to see the possible light to attain their terminal merge...

Comment: @DoubleKnot by adding a 'pra-' suffix to a word I mean 'before everything, in the beginning of all things'. In Russian it means 'grand' as in grandfather.

Comment: That's not inconsistent with prajña (~=pre+jina) which you can easily check its wikipedia explanation: *In the state of deep sleep, the Atman, limited by Prana, the vital breath, is called Prājña... that all that exist, all phenomena cosmic and psychical, are rooted in Prajñā*...

Comment: @DoubleKnot ah, I see now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Meanach thanks for your attention, I added some more questions.

Comment: @Meanach are my thoughts original?

Comment: I am not sure.  Your question has merit and has helped my own thinking. I think that it may need a further edit. Good work. I am particularly interested in the possibility of universal consciousness and value.

Comment: @Meanach could you please give me your email address to have a conversation?

Comment: I am sorry. I think that this would be a breach of the code of conduct. Best Wishes.

Answer (score 1):

The Sanskrit prana, mentioned by @Double Knot in his comment, as well as the Greek "πνεύμα" (pneuma) - which are equivalent - are the underlying concept of the unity of all that exists, independantly of our perception. It is considered as an objective reality, that - although we are constrantly interracting with it - can be reached directly only by non-ordinary states of consciousness, for example meditation and "αταραξία" (ataraxia) respectively.

Also this concept of "πνεύμα" (pneuma) is the Holy Spirit of Christianity and the inner "mechanics" of it are sudied by [pneumatology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumatology).

Now, returning back to earth, the ancient Greeks - starting with Parnenides - tried to identify this *essence* you are talking about, the "όν"/"τι είναι",  "what it is", the being (ontology) and incorporated it in the core of their philosophy. Nearly everything in ancient Greek philosophy is about this.

Later on Plato idealized this property of things (theory of Ideas/Platonic idealism) in accordance with your related thoughts, in his trying to objectify them, outside of human relativistic perception.

Finally Aristotle, linked the notion of this *essence* with the definition of things bounded by *logos*. Logos then, was considered as an intrinsic property of the things themselves (beings) ("τι είναι" - "ον" - "what it is" - being/entity) as per se predication. [link(7. Substance and Essence)...](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-metaphysics/#SubsEsse)

Subsequently this was the basis in which logic was used to identify things, to get to their meaning ([although with some conceptual discrepancy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/105009/can-reason-be-precisely-defined/105021#105021)).

What you are seeking is more or less the whole history of philosophy and theology.